# How to get values from data: part in ajax call

Tags: ajax, jmeter

$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: baseUrl + "query?v=21266702",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
           headers: {
                           "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken

```
       },
       data: JSON.stringify({ query: text, lang: "en", sessionId: reqIdToken }),
       success: function(data) {

                       xyz
                       }else{
                           setResponseForIT(data,"");
                       }
       },
       error: function() {
                       setResponse("Internal Server Error");
       }
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would assign this stuff to variables before sending the raw data.

You have the data right here :

query: text, lang: "en", sessionId: reqIdToken

you are basically building the JSON on the fly, just process these before by setting them as variables.

Update (for clarification) :

This is creating json for you based on the variables already set etc.

```
  JSON.stringify({ query: text, lang: "en", sessionId: reqIdToken })
```

This means you have access to  'text' and 'reqIdToken' and hence don't need to look at the 'data' variable that contains the json.  Just use reqIdToken if you want to know the sessionId.  (e.g. if (reqIdToken == "999") alert();)

Comment: In this,I need to extract sessionId .How can I extract JSON on fly?

Comment: session_id = reqIdToken   you are building the JSON right there with the stingify command, so the variable you are looking for is reqIdToken. You already have it to use, no need to do anything additional.